# Need to auto-populate info to fillable PDF online, be able to edit the data, and then save directly to server

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, adobe, acrofields

I'm working on a project where one of the main focuses is that the user be able to auto-populate an already-created industry-standard fillable template PDF form with data, then edit fields that were not populated (and/or fields that were populated) and save the form to the server as a PDF (with the fields populated).

Without flattening.

Because the user also needs the ability to recall that same file (the name and location of the file will be saved in the database) in order to make changes, print it and re-save it. 
Changes to populated fields do not necessarily need to be ported back to the database to "fix" the source data.

Most PDFs will be multiple pages but merging will not need to be done, because the pages will already be in the source PDF with the fillable fields.

I'm looking to do this in a PHP/MySQL environment on a CentOS system through an SSL connection. Any solution or combination of solutions would be welcome (FPDF, PDFtk, iText, Java, AJAX, Reader XI, etc).

Solutions I can buy that have already been figured out by a company are okay.

I've been searching SO and Google for days and can't seem to find an all-encompassing method that does exactly what I need. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: an unflattened pdf? why?

Comment: Because the user may need to edit the form fields again. Maybe I'm not using the correct term. I thought "flattening" meant that the fillable form fields would be non-editable (like when you flatten a PSD in Photoshop and can't edit the individual layers any more).

Comment: I know - but as long as the user's only accessing the document from within your environment, I cannot see why it needs to be a PDF. Surely, it's only once the document is ready for 'publication' (i.e. flattened) that it needs to be rendered to PDF?

Comment: There are hundreds of industry-standard documents, each with hundreds of fields that "may" be filled, each with twenty or so fields that will always be filled (first and last name, address, phone, etc.). To design an HTML form to populate a single three-page PDF form with something like FPDF would take a week alone.

Only the info that's on most forms would need to be populated from the database.

And these industry-standard forms will change every few years. It's much easier in the long run to design it like my description above, if I can.

Comment: And most important, the PDFs will already be made with fillable fields.

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this later .. I found the answer:

http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/

This product will do everything I've described above, returning the PDF form fields to the server in an array, which I will then join into a single variable and save in the database. Then, if the info is needed again (to edit or print in the form), it will be called, exploded, and sent to the PDF to populate before the PDF is downloaded to the client computer.

This is still theory, but I won't get to the implementation until later.